# @Bindable associated with method error-data binding

Tags: android

i am using data binding library to update the visibility of a TextView using attribute setter with a method

TextView:

```
<TextView
                    android:id="@+id/profileLblTtv"
                    android:layout_width="270dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="@string/profile_photo_gr"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:visibility="@{viewmodel.kalase(), default=gone}"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/reqfldsTtv"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
```

and bindable viewmodel method 'kalase':

```
@Bindable
public int kalase() {
    return userRole != null && userRole.getId() != 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE;
}
```

I am getting the following error: '@Bindable associated with method must follow JavaBeans convention kalase()'. Can anybody tell me what is going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

After a year and a half I could well be late to the party but...

The error is coming from the fact that you have an "@Bindable" tag on a function who's name does not conform to the JavaBeans convention. In order to make it confirm simply call your method `getKalase()` (instead of just `kalase()`) and refer to it in your layout file as `viewmodel.kalase` (without the parentheses)

Answer (score 0):

i think your use this method in a class that extend **BaseObservable** class. in this classes you must use method that observe your fields

```
UserRole userRole;

public void setUserRole(UserRole userRole) {
    this.userRole = userRole;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.userRole);
}

@Bindable
public int getUserRole() {
    return userRole != null && userRole.getId() != 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE;
}
```